# Google, "heavenly"/"original" and Baidu coordinates

Tags: meaning-in-context, software, technology

I'm helping answer [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444803/does-a-google-maps-coordinate-map-to-the-same-location-in-baidu-maps) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448149/googlemaps-gps-location-is-always-offset-in-china) on StackOverflow [and GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/what-causes-the-gps-offset-shift-in-china) regarding the unique coordinate system used in China, and its interaction with Baidu Maps.

While trying to machine translate the [Baidu Map coordinates conversion API](http://developer.baidu.com/map/jsdemo.htm#a5_2), I have these two strings:

- google坐标转成百度坐标 - Convert Google coordinates into Baidu coordinates
- 原始坐标转成百度坐标 - Convert ??? coordinates into Baidu coordinates

I'm trying to understand what the second description refers to. The "real" GPS coordinates (WSG-84), or the "original" i.e. approved by the State Council [GCJ-02 coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#Coordinate_systems)?

Google uses WGS-84 coordinates, so I'm inclining to believe the second option, but I see no reference to GCJ-02.

Comment: 原始 means "original", so I guess the second process is to convert original back to baidu coordinates?

Comment: @Flaudre: right, but I wonder what exactly "original" means. GPS, or GCJ-02?

Comment: Sorry, just realized you already got that far ;) i'll do some research, i am intereted in that stuff too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems to be GPS coordinates (WGS-84).

And yes, Google uses WGS-84 coordinates, but Google map uses State Council GCJ-02 coordinates in China.

So,

- google坐标转成百度坐标 : GCJ-02 TO BAIDU(GCJ-02 + BD09)
- 原始坐标转成百度坐标 : WGS-84 TO BAIDU(GCJ-02 + BD09)

Reference:
[百度地图API详解之坐标系转换](http://www.cnblogs.com/jz1108/archive/2011/10/11/2207245.html)
[GPS坐标换算为百度坐标](http://www.cnblogs.com/zhaohuionly/p/3142623.html)
[百度地图坐标转换（gps google 百度坐标相互转换）](http://malagis.com/baidu-map-coordinate-transformation.html)

Comment: [Google map shows a large mismatch between street maps and satellite imagery.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B014'39.4%22N+121%C2%B029'13.0%22E/@31.24427,121.48695,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

Comment: @DanDascalescu I'm not sure, but it seems the street maps uses GCJ-02, and satellite mode uses WGS-84, so there's obvious offset. http://www.cnblogs.com/glf123/archive/2012/02/06/2340033.html

Comment: This is correct, and I've created a demo that shows conversions from both GCJ-02 (called "google coordinates") and WGS-84 (called "original" coordinates) at http://jsbin.com/panomu/2

Comment: I've also created [Google Maps in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps#Google_Maps_in_China) on Wikipedia. google.cn/maps uses GCJ-02 for both street and satellite view, while google.com/maps uses GCJ-02 for street view and WSG-84 for satellite imagery, causing the [China GPS shift problem](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/what-causes-the-gps-offset-shift-in-china).